# datepicker doesn't working. I can't find that what am I missing in the code

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datePicker')
                .datepicker({
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                })
                .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                    // Revalidate the date field
                    $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
                });

            $('#eventForm').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    name: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The name is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    date: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The date is required'
                            },
                            date: {
                                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                message: 'The date is not a valid'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>



          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="date">
                    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This code shows the #datepicker input component but on clicking, it does not open. It also doesn't work on calling the simple $('#datepicker').datepicker(); method. Please provide some solution.

The simple datepicker() method comes with its own default settings but I have made my own customization in the this method.

In the div tag which is defined in the body tag but I have make it briefly. span tags are used embed icon with the datepicker input component. In this case I am using the glyphicon-calender. But before that I telling the compiler that I am going make an icon by writing class="input-group-addon add-on".

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.js and jquery ui needs jquery. put jquery on your top. and remove multiple bootstrap script definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

load jquery.js first and than load all js because juery is requisite for all js.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#datePicker')
                .datepicker({
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                })
                .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                    // Revalidate the date field
                    $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
                });

            $('#eventForm').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    name: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The name is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    date: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The date is required'
                            },
                            date: {
                                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                message: 'The date is not a valid'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>



          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="date">
                    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I included `jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` in the snippet and removed your redundant inclusions of bootstrap.

Comment: it still dont working. This response is for all 3 answers